# Should response to an email of accepted article with some comments

Tags: publications, communication

I received an email from one journal telling me that my paper will be accepted if I consider all the comments from the reviewer. They did not ask me to write a response to the reviewer as the comments are very minor as they said.

Should I respond to them saying that I am working on the comments?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably worth doing that, unless your revised paper can be re-submitted very soon. Don't leave them in suspense. You might even want to give an approximate date by which you will have the revisions ready.